# ANT_HOME location in Jdeveloper??

Tags: ant, jdeveloper

I am using JDEV 11g TP4 how do i know what my ANT_HOME path, and also how do i set ANT_HOME path
please let me know if anyone knows

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look under project properties->Ant->sub nodes